# activator always check new play framework version

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework, and want to build some demo. 
During playing, the activator always try to download new version jars. 
In real product development phase, I would like to stay on certain version before I make decision to go to new version. 
I didn't find any way to stop activator/play framework not to work in this way, and less document to introduce about it.

Comment: It will only check for the version that you mentioned in `plugins.sbt`, it may check whether they are there in local .ivy2 repo or not everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to `plugins.sbt` which will hopefully switch off Activator's requiring an internet connection.

```
offline := true
```

Of course, you need to have all the dependencies required to satisfy your build in local cache.